# Serialize Case Object Extending Trait

Tags: scala, serialization, playframework-2.0

Given a `trait Conjunction` with `AND` and `OR` case object sub-types:

```
  trait Conjunction
  case object AND extends Conjunction
  case object OR extends Conjunction
```

Using Play 2 JSON, I tried to write the following `Writes[Conjunction]`:

```
  implicit object ConjunctionWrites extends Writes[Conjunction] {
    implicit val orWrites: Writes[OR] = Json.writes[OR]
    implicit val andWrites: Writes[AND] = Json.writes[AND]

    def writes(c: Conjunction) = c match {
      case a@AND => Json.toJson(a)(andWrites)
      case o@OR => Json.toJson(o)(orWrites)
    }
  }
```

But I got a bunch of  `not found: type AND/OR` errors.

How can I serialize these `case object`s?

Comment: Why do you need `a` and `o` identifiers when you already have `AND` and `OR` objects?

Comment: good point. I was using them since I had been using `@` with other `Writes[...]` that I had been developing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a case object, you create a value with that name, but not a type. So `AND` and `OR` don't exist as types. If you want to refer to the type of a case object, use `.type`, e.g. `AND.type`.

However, the `Json.writes` macro only works on case classes, not case objects. You'll have to write your own definition:

```
implicit object ConjunctionWrites extends Writes[Conjunction] {
  def writes(c: Conjunction) = c match {
    case AND => Json.toJson("AND")
    case OR => Json.toJson("OR")
  }
}
```

Comment: note - I initially wrote `Json.toJson(AND)` rather than `"AND"`, resulting in a Stackoverflow. Of course it's a fishy mistake, but it's worthwhile to point out.